# Object has no attribute, but attribute is defined, not sure if indentation issue

Tags: python

The file that I'm running, example_market_data.py,

```
from marketplace_python.marketplace import Marketplace

marketplace = Marketplace('MY_API_KEY', 'MY_SECRET_KEY')

print(marketplace.ticker('btcmyr'))
print(marketplace.orderbook('btcmyr'))
print(marketplace.get_recent_trades('btcmyr', 1, 10))
```

And the imported file, marketplace.py,

```
from .market_data import MarketData

class Marketplace(MarketData):
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret

    def orderbook(self, pair: str) -> Dict(str, any):
        return MarketData.orderbook(self, pair)

    def ticker(self, pair: str) -> Dict(str, any):
        return MarketData.ticker(self, pair)

    def get_recent_trades(self, pair: str, page: int, per_page: int, sort: str = 'asc'):
        return MarketData.get_recent_trades(self, pair, page, per_page, sort)
```

When I run main.py, I get the
`AttributeError: 'Marketplace' object has no attribute 'orderbook'`.

I'm not sure if it's an indentation error as I have tried reordering the functions, for example `ticker` on top of `orderbook`, and other reordering styles, but I still get the same error.

I'm pretty sure there's no indentation error as my indentation are all spaces.

Am I missing out something?

Edit:
The directory of my project is

```
marketplace-python
-- examples
---- example_market_data.py
-- marketplace_python
---- marketplace.py
---- market_data.py
```

Comment: Also, know it is not secure to post your API keys on public forums. I would revoke those now if I were you

Comment: And another also: Please make this code available for copy-paste. as it is now, I can't run it because I don't have MarketData and other imports. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace-python\examples\example_market_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(marketplace.orderbook('btcmyr'))
AttributeError: 'Marketplace' object has no attribute 'orderbook'

Comment: I can't post the code here as I do not have the permission from my company to share it.
The `ticker` function is working. The `ticker` and the `orderbook` function are almost the same, the only difference is the URL of the API links.

Comment: @JamesOng Not being able to post code does not mean not being able to reproduce the error on other code which is not proprietary. Many times, attempting to reproduce in order to recreate the problem shows you the problem without actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about the code, I believe the problem is the type hints:

`-> Dict(str, any):` should be `-> Dict[str, any]:` with square brackets.

I came up with

```
from typing import Dict


class MarketData():
    def orderbook(self, pair) -> Dict[str, any]:
        pass

    def ticker(self, pair) -> Dict[str, any]:
        pass

    def get_recent_trades(self, pair, page, per_page, sort):
        pass


class Marketplace(MarketData):
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret

    def orderbook(self, pair: str) -> Dict[str, any]:
        return MarketData.orderbook(self, pair)

    def ticker(self, pair: str) -> Dict[str, any]:
        return MarketData.ticker(self, pair)

    def get_recent_trades(self, pair: str, page: int, per_page: int, sort: str = 'asc'):
        return MarketData.get_recent_trades(self, pair, page, per_page, sort)


marketplace = Marketplace('MY_API_KEY', 'MY_SECRET_KEY')

print(marketplace.ticker('btcmyr'))
print(marketplace.orderbook('btcmyr'))
print(marketplace.get_recent_trades('btcmyr', 1, 10))
```

which does not crash.

You can probably use similar code.

---

On another note, the code can be much more readable using `super()`:

For example, `return MarketData.orderbook(self, pair)`, having `MarketData` as a single super class, translates to `return super().orderbook(pair)` and so on.